Question on frequency sampling from Coursera DSP class 2.2.1c
In this video (from 2:00), it talks about why frequency sampling is a bad idea:
https://www.coursera.org/learn/dsp2/lecture/0QKiE/2-2-1-c-frequency-sampling
But I am not able to understand the details of the example used by the instructor.
Here is what I understand from the picture below:

Green line is the frequency response of an ideal low pass filter.
We want to get as close as possible of the green ideal one by having a few samples from it - So we have Gray dots.
But then, from the samples, we ended up having the non-ideal filter - Red line.

My question is, what is the purple sinc functions? And how do we get from the Gray dots to Red line?
It seems to me that each gray dot corresponds to a sinc function, and the sum of all those sinc functions becomes the Red line?
Is my understanding correct? If so, how each gray dot becomes the purple sinc?


You have another question open on the site already, and there are two good answers on that question. For the future, please try to accept an answer to previous questions before opening new ones.

Is there a way to accept an answer? I couldn't figure out how to do it

There should be a check mark next to an answer, by where the voting is.

found it, thanks!
